# Should I use static fields and interlocked together?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, interlocked

Should I use static fields and interlocked together, in cases when i need to provide thread safety and atomic operations with static fields, Is static fields are atomic by default? For example:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref Factory.DefectivePartsCount);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The field (assuming Int32) is atomic, not because it's static but because it's 32 bits.

How ever, `Factory.DefectivePartsCount += 1` requires a read and a write action on the variable so the whole operation is not thread-safe.

Comment: What does mean 32 bit (32 bit operating system - windows?). If i will using 64 bit system, is operations will be completely atomic?

Comment: Yes, when you target 64 bits then an Int64 would be atomic too. But why depend on that? And note, only _single_ operations will be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

`static` doesn't guarantee anything in terms of thread-safety. Hence, an increment will still not be atomic even if the variable is `static`. As such, you will still need to use classic synchronization mechanisms depending on the situation. In your case `Interlocked.Increment` is fine.